# Active Record calculations in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Could someone please help on how to use 'where' condition in this active record condition or why this throws error in rails 4.2?

```
 p = Project.first
  Project Load (34.6ms)  SELECT  `projects`.* FROM `projects`  ORDER BY `projects`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<Project id: 1, name: "First Project", created_at: "2015-12-29 16:27:42", updated_at: "2015-12-29 16:27:42"> 

2.2.1 :031 > p.tasks.sum(:priority)
   (26.8ms)  SELECT SUM(`tasks`.`priority`) FROM `tasks` WHERE `tasks`.`project_id` = 1
 => 9 

2.2.1 :032 > p.tasks.sum(:priority).where(:complete => 0)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT SUM(`tasks`.`priority`) FROM `tasks` WHERE `tasks`.`project_id` = 1
**NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for 9:Fixnum**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` returns `Fixnum`, not AR relation. You need to reverse `where` and `sum` order:

```
p.tasks.where(:complete => 0).sum(:priority)
```